# Excepciones en ejecución de webservice creado con WSDL Import GX15 U6

Tags: genexus

Estoy ejecutando servicios creados con WSDL Import y veo que ante una excepción del servicio, ya sea por timeout ú otro problema, explota una excepción .Net y la única forma de controlarla que encontré es utilizando código CSharp mediante un try/catch.

¿Hay forma de controlar esto en Genexus sin que le explote al usuario?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por las dudas, en el caso del timeout ya lo estoy revisando por el Location, aunque igual si se pasa, explota igual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setea la propiedad [CancelOnError](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7020,CancelOnError%20Property,) de la [Location Datatype](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6981,Location%20Data%20Type,) a `2`, y utiliza las funciones [GetSOAPErr](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7021,GetSOAPErr%20Function,) y [GetSOAPErrMsg](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7022,GetSOAPErrMsg%20Function,) para tomar las acciones que corresponda según la excepción.